# Add callback to DOM element created in subclass of web.list.Column

Tags: javascript, callback, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to modify the `web_tree_image` widget. Instead of just showing a small image in the column, I would like a larger image to appear when hovering or clicking. In order to achieve this, I am trying to add a callback after the widget is rendered, by overriding the `start` function, as explained in [the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html).

I therefore added the following code to [web_tree_image.js](https://github.com/OCA/web/blob/8.0/web_tree_image/static/src/js/web_tree_image.js):

```
openerp.web_tree_image = function (instance) {
    instance.web.list.Image = instance.web.list.Column.extend({
        // [...]
        start: function() {
            console.log("start called");
            // [... add callbacks ...]
        },
        // [...]
    });
};
```

However, the `start` function is never called, so this does not work.

I haven't fully understood the code path that usually leads to `start` being called, but it seems that it is somehow different for `web.list.Column`.

Should `start` be called and I am doing something wrong? Or is there another way of executing code after the DOM elements have been created?

Comment: Try with `include` instead of `extend`

Comment: It doesn't work with `include` either; also, the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html#subclassing-widget) clearly states that it should work with `extend`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Odoo but according to documentation you have to *Create the instance* with `var my_widget = new MyWidget(this);` and *Render and insert into DOM*  with `my_widget.appendTo(".some-div");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I still don't know why the `start` function is not called, this is a workaround:

```
openerp.web_tree_image = function (instance) {
    instance.web.list.Image = instance.web.list.Column.extend({
        // ...
        format: function (row_data, options) {
            // ...
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("DOM ready");
                // ... add callbacks ...
            }, 0);
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    });
};
```

By adding to the event queue with timeout 0, execution can be deferred until the relevant DOM elements have been created as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful).

Answer (score -1):

According documentation :

> The new class can then be used in the following manner:

```
// Create the instance
var my_widget = new MyWidget(this);
// Render and insert into DOM
my_widget.appendTo(".some-div");
```

> After these two lines have executed (and any promise returned by appendTo() has been resolved if needed), the widget is ready to be used.

---

> **Note**
>
> the insertion methods will start the widget themselves, and will return the result of start().
>
> If for some reason you do not want to call these methods, you will have to >first call render() on the widget, then insert it into your DOM and start it.

Comment: In the case described in my question, the widget is instantiated as part of a tree view that is defined in xml (and will indeed call the `appendTo` function under the hood). Note that I do not have a problem instantiating and seeing the widget, the problem is really just that `start` is not called.